# High poly from low poly with normal maps

Tags: normals

I have some low poly models with nice normal maps. Is it possible to create high poly model based on low poly model **and** normal map?

Subdivision surface doesn't work  in this case, as it will create high poly model from low poly, but it will not take normal map into account.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you convert the normal map into a height map in a program like CrazyBump or AwesomeBump. What this will do is add bump to the low poly model and enable you to give a slightly more high poly look. This however, may not give the best results.